# Strange behaviour SQL on comparing null values

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

I am comparing two tabels and am getting a strange result. I started with comparing two columns that are often null. Stating null = null always returns false. I found out that making is IS NULL for those columns works. The result shows a lot of double rows, which I dont understand.

So basically this row of data.data_1

```
column1     column2     column3     column4
apple       tree        NULL        NULL
```

and this row of data.data_2

```
column1     column2     column3     column4
apple       tree        NULL        NULL
```

returns after the following query

```
select
    br.column1, br.column2, br.column3, br.column4,  
    af.column1, af.column2
from
    data.data_1 as br
    left join data.data_2 as af on 
        (br.column1 = af.column1 and
        br.column2 = af.column2 and
        br.column3 IS NULL and af.column3 IS NULL and 
        br.column4 IS NULL and af.column4 IS NULL)

column1     column2     column3     column4     af.column1     af.column2     
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree 
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree 
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree      
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree      
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree      
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree      
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree      
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree      
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree      
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree      
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree      
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree      
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree      
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree      
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree
```

In stead of what I want it to return which would be:

```
column1     column2     column3     column4     af.column1     af.column2     
apple       tree        NULL        NULL         apple          tree
```

I could add a distinct function around it but I have the feeling that this would be an extra operation that should not be necessary.

Comment: NULL can be confusing. Does this article help? https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/

Comment: Perhaps you want to compare `AND ((br.column3 IS NULL AND af.column3 IS NULL) OR (br.column3 = af.column3))`

Comment: What do you mean when you say `double values`?

Comment: Maybe `COALESCE(br,col3, af.col3, br.col4, af.col4) IS NULL` could simplify your query a little bit?

Comment: `null = null` doesn't return *false*. It returns *unknown*. It's important to bear this in mind because `not (null = null)` is *also* unknown (and definitely not true)

Comment: The result doesn't match the sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1c0d2c3f1ff1ea370259490981cb0264)

```
SELECT *
FROM br
LEFT JOIN af
ON 
    br.col1 = af.col1 
AND br.col2 = af.col2 
AND COALESCE(br.col3, af.col3, br.col4, af.col4) IS NULL
```

The `COALESCE() IS NULL` ensures that all elements in this function (all columns) are `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you; will try this now and come back to here

Comment: @Zuenie added fiddle

Comment: This helped. Perfect

Comment: But this is essentially the same as the original query (the one with 4 IS NULLs)...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare two nullable columns and want to consider NULL = NULL then use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL = NULL                    THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'IDK' END       -- IDK
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not Equal' END -- Equal
```

Just plug this condition in your original query:

```
select
    br.column1, br.column2, br.column3, br.column4,
    af.column1, af.column2
from
    data.data_1 as br
    left join data.data_2 as af on (
        br.column1 = af.column1 and
        br.column2 = af.column2 and
        br.column3 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM af.column3 and
        br.column4 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM af.column4
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `left join` makes the query list all rows from `data_1`, no matter if there is a matching row in `data_2` or not.

Also, you join only when `column3` and `column4` are `NULL` in both tables - and list those `NULL` values. That´s a bit confusing, mildly put.

Your question would be much easier to answer if You would write what You want to achieve.

Comment: This is what I would expect yes. But it doesnt. It returns more rows then the input table